Is it permitted to redistribute the pandas document?
I wonder what the license of the pandas document is. Is it permitted to redistribute it? I would like the local readers to have fast and stable access to the document.
I have tried to find the license text on the pandas website but had no luck.
Thank you!

Yes, you can download the documentation. There is actually a link to a zipped HTML in the documentation start page
Pandas has an open source BSD-3 license, and its documentation is part of it.
